# Razor display date MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have html as

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth})

and property as

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invaild date.")]
    [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

controller code is as

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var member = (MembersViewModel)_db.Members.Single(f => f.Id == id);

        return View(member);
    }
```

Model Is as

```
 public class MembersViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GymId { get; set; }
    public Gym Gym { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Gym> Gyms { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invaild date.")]
    [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MembersViewModel(Member member)
    {
        return new MembersViewModel
        {
            BillingAddress = member.BillingAddress,
            FirstName = member.FirstName,
            Gyms = member.Gyms,
            Id = member.Id,
            LastName = member.LastName,
            MiddleName = member.MiddleName,
            ShippingAddress = member.ShippingAddress,
            DateOfBirth = member.DateOfBirth

        };

    }

    public static explicit operator Member(MembersViewModel member)
    {
        return new Member
        {
            BillingAddress = member.BillingAddress,
            FirstName = member.FirstName,
            Gyms = member.Gyms,
            Id = member.Id,
            LastName = member.LastName,
            MiddleName = member.MiddleName,
            ShippingAddress = member.ShippingAddress,
            DateOfBirth = member.DateOfBirth

        };

    }
}
```

It will allow me to select date from calender. And yes also save it in a database. But when I want to populate the saved date, then text box remains empty. I don't know why, even I get saved date and also pass to my model. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: How are you populating the date? Could you show the relevant code from your controller action that is rendering this view? Are you passing a model to it?

Comment: I have update the posting for my controller code, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I have solve this, not sure is it right or wrong but Work for me

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)

 @Html.Hidden("hiddenFieldDateofBirth", Model.DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

 <script>
    $("#DateOfBirth").val($("#hiddenFieldDateofBirth").val());
</script>
```